# Why aren't timestamps being interpreted if I run `history -r` from my .bashrc?

Tags: bash, rc

Okay, so something weird seems to be going on. When I run `history -r` interactively, it works as expected:

```
$ printf %b '#1401928364\necho\n' > /tmp/hist  # Make a test history file with timestamp information.
$ history -r /tmp/hist  # Read it into the current history.
$ history 3  # Bash has interpreted the history comment character such that timestamps don't appear on their own line.
  220  2014-06-05Thu17:59:55  history -r /tmp/hist  # Read it into the current history.
  221  2014-06-05Thu00:32:44  echo
  222  2014-06-05Thu18:00:07  history 3  # Bash has interpreted the history comment character such that timestamps don't appear on their own line.
```

However, running it from my `.bashrc` doesn't have the same expected behaviour:

```
$ printf %b 'history -r /tmp/hist\nhistory 3\n' > /tmp/bashrc  # Make a test bashrc file.
$ bash --rcfile /tmp/bashrc  # Run Bash with the test bashrc file; doesn't interpret the history comment character and prints a line containing ‘#1401928364’.
    1  #1401928364
    2  echo
```

I can confirm this with *shbot* on Freenode:

```
17:29:45 <JamesJRH> # printf %b '#1401928364\necho\n' > /tmp/hist; history -r /tmp/hist; history 3
17:29:47 <shbot>     1  printf %b '#1401928364\necho\n' > /tmp/hist; history -r /tmp/hist; history 3
17:29:47 <shbot>     2  echo
17:29:49 <JamesJRH> # printf %b '#1401928364\necho\n' > /tmp/hist; printf %b 'history -r /tmp/hist\nhistory 3\n' > /tmp/bashrc; bash --rcfile /tmp/bashrc
17:29:55 <shbot>     1  #1401928364
17:29:55 <shbot>     2  echo
```

So what's going on here?; how can I get it to work properly from my `.bashrc` file?

**Update:**

With my shell:

```
$ echo "$BASH_VERSION"; printf %b '#1401928364\necho\n' > /tmp/hist; printf %b 'export HISTTIMEFORMAT=\x27%F%a%T  \x27\nhistory -r /tmp/hist\nhistory 3\n' > /tmp/bashrc; bash --rcfile /tmp/bashrc
4.2.45(1)-release
    1  2014-06-05Thu19:42:31  #1401928364
    2  2014-06-05Thu19:42:31  echo
```

```
Summary                 interactive  bashrc
without HISTTIMEFORMAT  Succeeds.    Fails.
with HISTTIMEFORMAT     Succeeds.    Fails.
```

With *shbot*:

```
19:45:29 <JamesJRH> # echo "$BASH_VERSION"; printf %b '#1401928364\necho\n' > /tmp/hist; printf %b 'export HISTTIMEFORMAT=\x27%F%a%T  \x27\nhistory -r /tmp/hist\nhistory 3\n' > /tmp/bashrc; bash --rcfile /tmp/bashrc
19:45:36 <shbot> 4.3.18(1)-release
19:45:36 <shbot>     1  2014-06-05Thu00:32:44  echo
19:45:49 <JamesJRH> 42# echo "$BASH_VERSION"; printf %b '#1401928364\necho\n' > /tmp/hist; printf %b 'export HISTTIMEFORMAT=\x27%F%a%T  \x27\nhistory -r /tmp/hist\nhistory 3\n' > /tmp/bashrc; bash --rcfile /tmp/bashrc
19:45:56 <shbot> 4.2.47(2)-release
19:45:56 <shbot>     1  2014-06-05Thu00:32:44  echo
19:46:08 <JamesJRH> 41# echo "$BASH_VERSION"; printf %b '#1401928364\necho\n' > /tmp/hist; printf %b 'export HISTTIMEFORMAT=\x27%F%a%T  \x27\nhistory -r /tmp/hist\nhistory 3\n' > /tmp/bashrc; bash --rcfile /tmp/bashrc
19:46:15 <shbot> 4.1.11(1)-release
19:46:15 <shbot>     1  2014-06-05Thu00:32:44  echo
```

```
Summary                 interactive  bashrc
without HISTTIMEFORMAT  Succeeds.    Fails.
with HISTTIMEFORMAT     Succeeds.    Succeeds.
```

So what could be causing this difference between my Bash and *shbot*'s?

Answer (score 1):

Does it work if you set the `HISTTIMEFORMAT` env. variable first, and then you try to run history again?

```
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%F %T "
```

If `HISTTIMEFORMAT` is not set, then the timestamps are not written in the history file.

Comment: No. In my real `.bashrc` I have `export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F%a%T  '` before the reading part. Also, it evidently works without it when reading a history file interactively (see the _shbot_ reply). According to Bash's manpage, if `HISTTIMEFORMAT` isn't null then it will save timestamps to the history file. It shouldn't need it to be set in order to read in the history file, it's just that `history` won't print them. Have you tried it?

Comment: On the other hand, this does work for _shbot_, just not in _my_ `.bashrc`... confusing. I'll try to pin down what's different.

Comment: I couldn't pin it down; I tried on different versions of Bash for _shbot_, but for all versions it works for _shbot_ but not for me.

Answer (score 0):

Alas!!

I have finally pinned down the difference between my shell and that of *shbot*, and it was indeed the Bash *version* as I had first suspected, but *shbot* through me off the trail by lying to me! Well, actually it's due to an implementation detail of *shbot*, but this variation on my commands gives the true story of which versions work or not:

```
03:31:11 <JamesJRH> # printf %b '#1401928364\necho\n' > /tmp/hist; printf %b 'echo "$BASH_VERSION"\nexport HISTTIMEFORMAT=\x27%F%a%T  \x27\nhistory -r /tmp/hist\nhistory 3\n' > /tmp/bashrc; bash --rcfile /tmp/bashrc
03:31:18 <shbot> 4.3.18(1)-release
03:31:18 <shbot>     1  2014-06-05Thu00:32:44  echo
03:31:25 <JamesJRH> # printf %b '#1401928364\necho\n' > /tmp/hist; printf %b 'echo "$BASH_VERSION"\nexport HISTTIMEFORMAT=\x27%F%a%T  \x27\nhistory -r /tmp/hist\nhistory 3\n' > /tmp/bashrc; bash42 --rcfile /tmp/bashrc
03:31:32 <shbot> 4.2.47(2)-release
03:31:32 <shbot>     1  2014-06-06Fri03:31:24  #1401928364
03:31:32 <shbot>     2  2014-06-06Fri03:31:24  echo
```

So now the summaries refer to versions!

With Bash 4.2 and earlier:

```
Summary                 interactive  bashrc
without HISTTIMEFORMAT  Succeeds.    Fails.
with HISTTIMEFORMAT     Succeeds.    Fails.*
```

** Tested on 4.2.47(2)-release, 4.2.45(1)-release, 4.2.25(1)-release, 4.2.8(1)-release, 4.1.11(1)-release, 4.0.38(1)-release, 3.2.51(2)-release, 3.2.39(1)-release.*

From Bash 4.3 onwards:

```
Summary                 interactive  bashrc
without HISTTIMEFORMAT  Succeeds.    Fails.
with HISTTIMEFORMAT     Succeeds.    Succeeds.*
```

** Tested on 4.3.18(1)-release.*

Still not entirely sure why `HISTTIMEFORMAT` isn't needed interactively but is needed in the `.bashrc`, but that isn't a problem.

So the direct answer to the question: They are only interpreted from the `.bashrc` if both the version of Bash used is at least 4.3 and the `HISTTIMEFORMAT` variable is set and not null. In my case `HISTTIMEFORMAT` was already set in my `.bashrc` so it was the version that was the problem. Clearly this is a bug and this bug has been fixed.

Just now need to go and install Bash 4.3… :-)